How should I visualise my interpretation?
I'm doing an analysis on how wind turbine parameters affect wind speed. Dataset from: https://datadryad.org/stash/dataset/doi:10.5061/dryad.vx0k6djxg
mod4= lm(wind_speed~turbine_distance* rotor_size *tower_height+ 
           turbine_operation_bin+number_turbines, data = d2)

After stepwise deletion, this was the summary output
                           Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)                8.089e+00  1.943e+00   4.164 3.16e-05 ***
rotor_size                -1.117e-01  1.780e-02  -6.274 3.67e-10 ***
tower_height              -1.565e-02  1.005e-02  -1.557     0.12    
turbine_operation_binTRUE  5.126e-01  1.264e-02  40.558  < 2e-16 ***
number_turbines            7.961e-02  5.357e-03  14.860  < 2e-16 ***
rotor_size:tower_height    3.962e-04  9.111e-05   4.348 1.39e-05 ***

For every 1m increase in rotor_size, the wind_speed at 10m above ground decreased by -1.117e-01 ± 1.780e-02  m/s (p=3.67e-10), and this decrease is lessened by 3.962e-04 ± 9.111e-05 m/s for every 1m increase in tower_height (p= 1.39e-05)
tower_height is a continuous variable but I tried to bin it into short and tall (lower 50%-> short, higher 50% -> tall)
d3 <- d2 %>% mutate(tower_height = 
    case_when(tower_height<-floor(0.5*(nrow(d2))) ~'short',
              tower_height<-ceiling(0.5*(nrow(d2)))~'tall')
d3$tower_height = as.factor(d3$tower_height)
mod5= lm(wind_speed~turbine_distance*rotor_size*tower_height+ 
           turbine_operation_bin+number_turbines, data = d3)
summary(mod5)
Coefficients:
                                               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                                   2.216e+00  2.985e-01   7.424 1.24e-13 ***
turbine_distance                              9.164e-04  1.113e-03   0.823  0.41042    
rotor_size                                   -7.813e-03  2.825e-03  -2.766  0.00568 ** 
tower_heighttall                              4.095e+00  4.660e-01   8.787  < 2e-16 ***
turbine_operation_binTRUE                     5.631e-01  1.282e-02  43.941  < 2e-16 ***
number_turbines                               6.409e-02  5.421e-03  11.822  < 2e-16 ***
turbine_distance:rotor_size                  -1.009e-05  1.045e-05  -0.966  0.33416    
turbine_distance:tower_heighttall            -2.294e-03  1.743e-03  -1.317  0.18804    
rotor_size:tower_heighttall                  -3.459e-02  4.095e-03  -8.445  < 2e-16 ***
turbine_distance:rotor_size:tower_heighttall  2.196e-05  1.533e-05   1.433  0.15185
    
ggplot(data=d3, aes(x=rotor_size, y=wind_speed)) + geom_point(aes(colour=tower_height)) + geom_smooth(method=lm, aes(colour=tower_height))

The resulting graph shows that the wind_speed decreases at a faster rate with tall tower_height. But the summary output shows that the decrease is lessened with increasing tower_height. I don't know what is wrong, and whether to use this graph in my presentation.


I think you should edit your post and show the model summary output for the "categorized" tower_height variable.

And your mutate command looks strange to me.

Hi Edward! Thanks for the feedback, I've edited the post and pasted the summary output for the categorised tower_height variable. Also for the mutate command, I also tried categorising according to the median (199).  But the resulting graph is the same.  d3 <- d2 %>% mutate(tower_height = case_when(tower_height<199 ~ 'short',tower_height >= 199 ~ 'tall'))

Your new output now matches the graph.

I think it might be worth looking at tower height as a continuous variable and also doing a correlation/plot against the ratio of tower height over rotor size which might be more relevant. Depending on what it is you are measuring it could be mostly that super large rotors have more bearing friction and even on "tall" towers still have some part of their sweep circle in the slower ground boundary layer. I find it hard to believe that the wind speed is decreasing with height on the scale that your graph implies.

Hi Martin! Our first model (mod4) treated tower_height as a continuous variable, but I don’t know why, when I split tower_height into tall and short the graph contradicts the mod4 interpretation

Categorizing a continuous variable can hide or even distort the relationship if it isn't linear. The graph does not contradict your second model.

Thank you Edward and Martin for all your help!

If you tag your comments with @whoever we get to see your replies. Splitting a continuous variable into high and low can like this introduce nasty side effects that depend on exactly where you put the threshold. If 100m blades are on "short" 190m towers h/r = 1.9 and say the 120m blades are on "tall" 200m towers then h/r = 1.7. I think you will find that h/r is the physical parameter for correlating windspeed/performance against. I'd hazard a guess that there is an intrinsic bias on the values of h/r becoming smaller as r gets larger due to engineering costs.
